# Select the first column in a dynamically created table and post in in a pop-up window

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a page that creates a table after retrieving data from a mysql database. Each row has a link. My problem is that I have to pass the text in the first cell of the row (which is the primary key that i will also use in the pop-up window) where the link was clicked.

```
<TABLE border="1" height="800px" width="600px" id="myTable">

        <br>
        <br>
        <caption>*Please close or update the following WAR first!</b></caption>
        <br>
        <th><center><b>Weekly Report ID</b> </center></th>
        <th><center><b>Report Category</b> </center></th>
        <th><center><b>Problem Title</b> </center></th>
        <th><center><b>Closure</b> </center></th>
        <th><center><b>Action</b> </center></th>
        <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $rptid    = $row['weeklyReportId'];
        $rptcat   = $row['reportCategory'];
        $rptptl   = $row['problemTitle'];
        $rptcls   = $row['closure'];

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $rptid; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $rptcat; ?></td>
            <td width="50"><?php echo $rptptl; ?></td>
            <td width="20"><?php echo $rptcls; ?></td>
            <td width="20"><a href="#"><img src="../MyImages/Text Edit Icon.jpg" width="15" height="15" onClick="return popitup('update_popup.php'); "></img> </a></td>
            <!--<td width="10"> <input type="image" src="../MyImages/Text Edit Icon.jpg" width="15" height="15" id="target"></input></td>-->
        </tr>       

        <?php
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
        mysql_close($dbhandle);

        ?>

    </TABLE>
```

I also have a Javascript that opens the popup window

```js
<!-- Function for popup window
var newwindow;
var def1='';

function popitup(url,name) {

    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=500,width=800');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()
    }
    return false;
}

// -->
```

Comment: Why can't you even format your question to see if it comes well?

Comment: please validate your html, you are using depricated elements `<font>` and the `<br>` tags are in the wrong place. [Get started here](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Comment: Please have some suggestions on how to get the value of the cell where the link was clicked, i could probably start from that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario you can use `update_popup.php?rptid=<?php echo urlencode($rptid);?>`.

Comment: it showed in the URL, thanks for that! but how can i display that in a text field at the pop-up window? I'm new working with this...

Comment: Thanks so much, i used $_GET to do it!

Comment: You can do it clientside by using document.location.search, or indeed do it server side. Assuming you are creating some sort of form, you probably want to validate that the rptid is valid and in case of error show a warning.